# How do you changed the loading text color and background color or Material UI LoadingButton

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I'm using this import `LoadingButton from '@mui/lab/LoadingButton';`

I want to have a different background colour and text colour than the default one when the button is in a loading state.

the documentation says to the target ".MuiLoadingButton-root". but I don't understand how to target any of the root components. I'm still fairly new to material UI.

Answer (score 2):

What is being explained in the documentation is that you can style the root component (the LoadingButton container div) by styling the class "MuiLoadingButton-root".

Basically, you need to have a css styling targeting this class and call it inside your component:

```css
.MuiLoadingButton-root {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```